# dyld: Library not loaded:

Tags: ios, xcode

App crashes on stimulator iPhone 6s/iPhone 6 Plus (9.0 version) but it works on other iphone with same ios Version 9.0 . 
App is running on all iPhone stimulator with ios version greater than 9.0

I tried following things but still getting same error:

Cleaned, restart xCode, restart mac, pod update, Cleared derived data from xCode> Preference

Below error comes while running app :

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

what should I try now?

Comment: vision framework is only available from iOS 11+.

Comment: But it is working on ios 10 , and also on 2 iphone device with 9, can you pls share official document link where its showing minimum required ios version ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision

Comment: @Priyal , I am not using apple's vision framework ...I am using google's vision to build text recognition .  I didn't find anywhere in there release note about the minimum iOS version support